# How can I find dates ranges with no data from an effective dated table with SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a little bit confusing so i'll try to clarify.

let's say I have an employee table like this

| employee | eff_Dt | end_effective_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1900-01-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 |
| 1 | 2021-02-02 | 9999-01-01 |
| 2 | 1900-01-01 | 9999-01-01 |
| 3 | 1900-01-01 | 2015-12-31 |
| 3 | 2016-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 4 | 1900-01-01 | 2016-01-01 |
| 4 | 2018-01-01 | 9999-01-01 |

Employees 1 and 2 are fine. They have a full effective dated history from 1900-01-01 to 9999-12-31. All of my employee records need that.

The SQL I need is to find records like 3 and 4. In the case of employee 3, we are missing the data from 2020-01-02 to 9999-01-01 and for employee 4 we are missing data from 2016-01-02 to 2017-12-31.

How can I develop a query that will return these records? I am on Oracle SQL - would prefer an ANSI SQL solution if possible but if the best solution is uses oracle specific functions than it is what it is. I do not have access to create indices or create stored procedures. This can only be done via query.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your employee records shouldn't need that. You should just start your queries with a calendar table and left join the data to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to count days. The 2958098 is amount of days between 1900-01-01 and 9999-01-01.

This query will return employees 3 and 4

```
select employee, sum(end_effective_date - eff_dt) 
  from test 
  group by employee 
 having sum(end_effective_date - eff_dt) < 2958098;
```

UPD: Same query without hard-coded values

```
select employee, sum(end_effective_date - eff_dt) 
  from test 
 group by employee 
having sum(end_effective_date - eff_dt) < (date'9999-01-01' - date'1900-01-01' + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you - this was the most elegant solution!

Comment: It was an interesting question. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

If you want the employees missing dates:

```
select employee
from t
group by employee
having min(eff_Dt) <> date '1900-01-01' or
       max(end_effective_date) <> date '9999-01-01';
```

If you want the specific missing time periods, use `lead()` for most of them . . . and then `union all` to get the first one:

```
select employee,
       end_effective_date + interval '1' day as missing_eff_dt,
       next_eff_dt - interval '1' day as missing_end_dt
from (select t.*, lead(eff_dt) as next_eff_dt
      from t
     ) t
where next_eff_dt > end_effective_date + interval '1' day
union all
select employee, date '1900-01-01',
       min(eff_dt) - interval '1' day
from t
group by employee
where min(eff_dt) > date '1900-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it well, you need to find records for employees who have gaps between end dates and start dates, and those who don't have 9999-01-01 as the max end_date. The query below will work for that purpose.

```sql
select EMPLOYEE, EFF_DT, END_EFFECTIVE_DATE 
from (
    select tt.*
    , count(distinct grp)
        over(partition by EMPLOYEE) cnt
    , max(END_EFFECTIVE_DATE)
        over(partition by EMPLOYEE order by EFF_DT desc) max_END_EFFECTIVE_DATE
    from (
    select t.*
    , case 
        when EFF_DT != nvl(
                lag(END_EFFECTIVE_DATE, 1)over(partition by EMPLOYEE order by EFF_DT)
                , date '-4712-01-01'
                )+ 1 
            then row_number()over (partition by EMPLOYEE order by EFF_DT)
        else null
      end
      grp
    from your_table
    ) tt
)ttt
where cnt > 1 
or max_END_EFFECTIVE_DATE < date '9999-01-01'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query below uses the Tabibitosan method to stitch together the adjacent time periods. The method itself uses the analytic `sum()` function and standard aggregation; it works almost unchanged in any SQL dialect that supports basic analytic functions.

The output shows only the employees with incomplete data. It shows uninterrupted periods of "effectivity"; if data is "complete", then there should be only one such interval for the employee, from 1 JAN 1900 to 1 JAN 9999. Those are excluded; the output shows the employees with gaps at the beginning, in the middle, and/or the end, and for those employees it shows the interval (or intervals) of "effectivity".

While you didn't request this, the query could be modified easily to show the "**missing**" periods for each employee (the periods when they were **not** effective).

```
with
  t (employee, eff_dt, end_effective_date, grp) as (
    select employee, eff_dt, end_effective_date,
           end_effective_date - sum(end_effective_date + 1 - eff_dt)
                                over (partition by employee order by eff_dt)
    from   sample_data
  )
select employee, min(eff_dt) as eff_dt, max(end_effective_date) as end_dt
from   t
group  by employee, grp
having min(eff_dt)             != date '1900-01-01'
    or max(end_effective_date) != date '9999-01-01'
order  by employee, eff_dt
;

  EMPLOYEE  EFF_DT      END_DT    
----------  ----------  ----------
         3  1900-01-01  2020-01-01
         4  1900-01-01  2016-01-01
         4  2018-01-01  9999-01-01
```